# Invalid path in Angular library

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, tsconfig, angular-library

I am using Angular library and have the following folder structure:

```
coollibrary
  - components
    - my.component.ts
  - services
    - my.service.ts
public_api.ts
```

In public_api, I export the component and service and make the library build.
After that I can import the necessary things in my project using

```
import { MyComponent } from 'coollibrary';
```

but I can not use the following path:

```
import { MyComponent  } from 'coollibrary/components'
```

Can I somehow achieve this behavior?

I generate library with following command:

```
ng generate coollibrary
```

and after build it with following command:

```
ng build --project coollibrary
```

My tsconfig:

```
...
"paths": {
      "coollibrary": [
        "dist/coollibrary"
      ],
      "coollibrary/*": [
        "dist/coollibrary/*"
      ]
    }
...
```

Comment: do you have this "library" in your node_modules folder?

Comment: @codedawi no. I build library and use it in dist folder.

Comment: I think you'll need an `index.ts` that re-exports the components in the `components` directory.

Comment: @lellelskii I was just reading some docs and it might be as simple as using a relative path in your tsconfig.json ex. "./dist/coollibrary" Give that a shot and let me know.

See: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#use-typescript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies

Comment: I think the library is generated with ng g library <libName>, to just build the library you should just run ng build <libName>

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: why do you need to import it like `import { MyComponent  } from 'coollibrary/components'` while it work when you import it like `import { MyComponent } from 'coollibrary'` also all the components added in the public_api.ts file will be available for import after you build the library

Comment: @ laiju  because if you want to use this ( import { MyComponent } from 'coollibrary' ) , you have to load all part of the coollibrary but if you use 
( import { MyComponent } from 'coollibrary/components' ) you load only this component;   you can assume that you have 50 components in the coollibrary library if you import the MyComponent  like this (  import { MyComponent } from 'coollibrary'  ) , Angular loads all 50 components , That's awful