# Store global types in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have some globally used enums, interfaces or bigger classes.

Like:

```
export interface LogMessage {
   code: number;
   message: string;
}
```

Where should I store them? What is the best practice, specifically for Angular? I hope this question is not too generic. I just want a scaling solution which fits for very big applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just create a angular library and put these types in that library then you will be able to use them in multi angular application as a single library

```
ng g library <name> [options]
```

file structure can be like this

```
classes /
     ...
interfaces / 
     ...
enums / 
     ...
types /
    ...
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with library. Imagine that we have a lot of class in the library , and where we want to use one of that class we have to load all the library
while we need one class ; what is your solution here ?

Comment: when you are is build only needed classes will be ship to production any unused class or enum will not be part of you app , so if you don't used it don't warry about it

Comment: It can relate to class/interface/component in the library ?  see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532292/invalid-path-in-angular-library